# Connect to googlesheets via shiny in R with googlesheets4

Tags: r, shiny, google-sheets-api, googlesheets4

I'm trying to use an updated version of this [example](https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets/blob/master/inst/shiny-examples/10_read-write-private-sheet/global.R) to connect to a private googlesheet via shiny, and deploy this app on the shinyapps.io server. The user is not required to authenticate to a google account as the app uses a specified pre-existing googlesheet.

I've followed this [example](https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets/blob/master/inst/shiny-examples/10_read-write-private-sheet/global.R) (partly copied here), attempting to save the token to my shiny app:

```
# previous googlesheets package version:
shiny_token <- gs_auth() # authenticate w/ your desired Google identity here
saveRDS(shiny_token, "shiny_app_token.rds")
```

but tried to update it to googlesheets4, like this:

```
ss <- gs4_get("MY GOOGLE DOC URL") # do the authentication once, manually.
ss
gs4_has_token() # check that the token exists

# get token
ss_token <- gs4_token()
# save the token
save(ss_token, file = "APP PATH ... /data/tk.rdata")
```

Then in the app, I have placed this code outside the `shinyApp()` function.

```
load("data/tk.rdata")

googlesheets4::gs4_auth(token = ss_token, use_oob = T)
```

In the app, I connect to a google doc from the app, using a hardcoded id obtained from
`ss$spreadsheet_id` above. The app works locally.

After attempting to deploy the app to the server I get the error "...Can't get google credentials. Are you running googlesheets4 in a non-interactive session?... etc" I thought that the token would contain sufficient information for this.

I'd be grateful if anyone can point me to a guide to setting this up, and also comment on whether this approach (saving a token on the shinyapps.io) is safe?

I've looked at other examples, but it seems most are for the previous version of `googlesheets`

Comment: the generation of the token should be done only once.

Comment: Yes, I generated it once, and then saved it with the idea to use it permanently for authentication

Comment: You could try using the [googleAuthR package](https://code.markedmondson.me/googleAuthR/articles/setup.html). I don't think shiny authentication has been properly implemented in gargle yet (which googlesheets4 uses).

Comment: Thanks. Reading the documentation on this package and gargle,  I need non-interactive access for the above use, seems the recommeded way is through a  service account token. I have tried this, creating a project on google platform, activating the APIs required, and downloading the service account json, and passing this to `gs4_auth()` function, but still didn't have any success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just follow the instructions in [this](https://medium.com/@JosiahParry/googlesheets4-authentication-for-deployment-9e994b4c81d6) link:

```
# designate project-specific cache
options(gargle_oauth_cache = ".secrets")
# check the value of the option, if you like
gargle::gargle_oauth_cache()
# trigger auth on purpose to store a token in the specified cache
# a broswer will be opened
googlesheets4::sheets_auth()
# see your token file in the cache, if you like
list.files(".secrets/")
# sheets reauth with specified token and email address
sheets_auth(
 cache = ".secrets",
 email = "youremail"
 )
```

Comment: This is working on shiny server. Any comments on the security of this method vs the service account? eg in terms of having the .secrets cache on the shiny server?

Comment: Any idea why `googlesheets4::sheets_auth()` is not in the package anymore? Do you have any workaround?

Comment: @storaged `googlesheets4::sheets_auth()` was deprecated in v1.0.0. You should now use `gs4_auth()` instead. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70215575/16510400) for more detail.

Answer (score 21):

On 21-Jul-2021 googlesheets4 [deprecated some of its function when releasing v1.0.0](https://github.com/tidyverse/googlesheets4/releases/tag/v1.0.0).

I have updated [volfi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63917696/16510400) to work with googlesheets4 v1.0.0. 
It also works when deploying to shinyapps.io.

## Set up non-interactive authentication

```
library(googlesheets4)
    
# Set authentication token to be stored in a folder called `.secrets`
options(gargle_oauth_cache = ".secrets")

# Authenticate manually
gs4_auth()

# If successful, the previous step stores a token file.
# Check that a file has been created with:
list.files(".secrets/")

# Check that the non-interactive authentication works by first deauthorizing:
gs4_deauth()

# Authenticate using token. If no browser opens, the authentication works.
gs4_auth(cache = ".secrets", email = "your@email.com")
```

## Example - add data to Gooogle Sheet

Create a Google Sheet on [Google Sheets](https://github.com/tidyverse/googlesheets4/releases/tag/v1.0.0) and copy the sheet's url.

```
library(googlesheets4)
gs4_auth(cache=".secrets", email="your@email.com")

ss <- gs4_get("https://docs.google.com/path/to/your/sheet")
sheet_append(ss, data.frame(time=Sys.time()))
```

If deploying your app to shinyapps.io make sure to deploy the file in the `.secrets` folder.

Comment: how to add the .secrets file if it is hidden?

Comment: gs4_auth() adds a folder called .secrests/ and puts a token file in it.

Comment: Is there a way to authenticate manually if I only have access to 
a server console? `git pull`ing the `.secrets` folder is not working for me

Answer (score 4):

I am posting here because I started from this thread on this journey, and want to share what finally worked after many hours of having a go, reading gargle, googledrive, and googlesheets4 documentation and oh so many other posts on this issue.

1. I first used the googlesheets4 method gs4_auth() to obtain a credential and stored it in a `.secrets` folder. As described in this thread and [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/googlesheets4/issues/184). This worked on my desktop and I was excited. It did not work on shinyapps.io or on my Ubuntu 18.4 instance of shiny-server that I have on an AWS EC2 instance. The error was something like this:

"Error in ... : Can't get Google credentials.Are you running googledrive in a non-interactive session? Consider: `drive_deauth()` to prevent the attempt to get credentials. Call `drive_auth()` directly with all necessary specifics."

2. Then I tried an approach starting from [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/googlesheets4/issues/184) and taking me to [here](https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/non-interactive-auth.html#project-level-oauth-cache)
   Somehow this did work on shinyapps.io but still not on my Ubuntu shiny server.
3. **This worked:** I pursued a Google service account approach as described [here](https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/get-api-credentials.html#service-account-token) and created a project, then a service account for the project, added Google Sheets API to the project, then downloaded a key as a JSON file. I then used at the top of my app_server.R file `googlesheets4::gs4_auth(path = './<path to hidden JSON file folder I called .token>/.token/<JSON key file>.json')`. This still did not work until the final step that is not clearly explained almost anywhere I looked which is to go to the Google sheet in question, and "share" it with the `client_email` email address from the JSON key file, giving it editor permissions, in my case. This was finally well explained in this random article:  https://robocorp.com/docs/development-guide/google-sheets/interacting-with-google-sheets

Finally read and write access for my app from shiny server on my AWS server instance. I really hope someone finds this useful.

Comment: I tried 1. following the answer by Johan Ejstrud and it worked on shinyapps.io. Did you try his approach?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues while working on a Shiny app for data entry. The idea was to punch in the data and write it automatically to a google sheet. I followed this [tutorial](https://www.jdtrat.com/blog/connect-shiny-google/) at first and everything worked like a charm locally. However, I started loosing my temper while deploying on [shinyapps.io](https://www.shinyapps.io/). Upon inspection of the logs I stumbled on the same error messages as the OP.

I found out that the approach was wrong because I was generating two very similar tokens in the same folder and this presumably messes up authentication (Disclaimer: I am not a developer)

```
# WRONG!

# interactive, generates token
options(gargle_oauth_cache = ".secrets")
googledrive::drive_auth()
googlesheets4::gs4_auth()

# non-interactive
googledrive::drive_auth(cache = ".secrets", email = "blabla@email.com")
googlesheets4::gs4_auth(cache = ".secrets", email = "blabla@email.com")
```

After a bit of research, I found this [googlesheet4 documentation page](https://googlesheets4.tidyverse.org/articles/drive-and-sheets.html) that explained it all. The idea is to coordinate authentication to avoid generating a shitload of tokens when you need only one.

```
# RIGHT!

# interactive, generates token
options(gargle_oauth_cache = ".secrets")
googledrive::drive_auth()

# non-interactive
googledrive::drive_auth(cache = ".secrets", email = "blabla@email.com")
googlesheets4::gs4_auth(token = drive_token())
```