# Problem in `gs4_auth()` and `gs4_deauth()` of googlesheets4

Tags: r, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, shiny

My ultimate goal is to deploy the app on shinyapps.io, and everyone without google account could edit my Google sheet.
First, I follow this guide https://stackoverflow.com/a/70215575/22331901, it seems to meets my requirement.
But, I failed in `gs4_auth()`, it did open my edge, and edge returns `Authentication complete. Please close this page and return to R.` Then, in the console, it returns

```
> library(googlesheets4)
> options(gargle_oauth_cache = ".secrets")
> gs4_auth()
Waiting for authentication in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
Authentication complete.
Error in `gs4_auth()`:
! Can't get Google credentials.
ℹ Are you running googlesheets4 in a non-interactive session? Consider:
• Call `gs4_deauth()` to prevent the attempt to get credentials.
• Call `gs4_auth()` directly with all necessary specifics.
ℹ See gargle's "Non-interactive auth" vignette for more details:
ℹ <https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/non-interactive-auth.html>
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_trace()
<error/googlesheets4_error>
Error in `gs4_auth()`:
! Can't get Google credentials.
ℹ Are you running googlesheets4 in a non-interactive session? Consider:
• Call `gs4_deauth()` to prevent the attempt to get credentials.
• Call `gs4_auth()` directly with all necessary specifics.
ℹ See gargle's "Non-interactive auth" vignette for more details:
ℹ <https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/non-interactive-auth.html>
---
Backtrace:
    ▆
 1. └─googlesheets4::gs4_auth()
Run rlang::last_trace(drop = FALSE) to see 3 hidden frames.
> rlang::last_trace(drop = FALSE)
<error/googlesheets4_error>
Error in `gs4_auth()`:
! Can't get Google credentials.
ℹ Are you running googlesheets4 in a non-interactive session? Consider:
• Call `gs4_deauth()` to prevent the attempt to get credentials.
• Call `gs4_auth()` directly with all necessary specifics.
ℹ See gargle's "Non-interactive auth" vignette for more details:
ℹ <https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/non-interactive-auth.html>
---
Backtrace:
    ▆
 1. └─googlesheets4::gs4_auth()
 2.   └─googlesheets4:::gs4_abort(...)
 3.     └─cli::cli_abort(...)
 4.       └─rlang::abort(...)
```

I tried any answer on stackoverflow, all failed, nothing changed.

1. update `curl`
2. update `gargle`
3. install `googlesheets4` from github

Furthermore, `gs_deauth()` even also didn't work

```
> gs4_deauth()
> ss <- "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Cw9YSvzsGW5JDFptZ4-qVE0veNthwU3lxsZErk1So5E/edit?usp=sharing"
> dat <- read_sheet(ss)
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Timeout was reached: [sheets.googleapis.com] Failed to connect to sheets.googleapis.com port 443 after 10009 ms: Timeout was reached
```

Is it possible that this is due to the internet? I'm in China and I'm using SSR